# .htaccess to redirect subdomain to another domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect  *.domain.com/* to *.otherdomain.com/* 
and domain.com/* to otherdomain.com/* which is on the other server.

Also, I want the address bar to change to the new domain

eg: hi.domain.com/there -> hi.otherdomain.com/there

I found some examples of .htaccess but cannot make both rules in one.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this in your .htaccess in the root.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+\.)?domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1otherdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It works on domain.com   ,    domain.com/subdir   but not on  subdomain.domain.com  (subdomain redirection not working).. how can I fix it?

Comment: Your setup has to be able to recognize the subdomains from your main domain. Either make sure your vhost includes subdomains in your `ServerAlias` or use this rule under the subdomains you want to redirect.